# Xamarin : use Android WebView EvaluateJavascript

Tags: javascript, android-webview, xamarin

I would like to use the Android WebView [EvaluateJavascript method](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript%28java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E%29) with Xamarin in Visual Studio but this method is not available :

[image]

Is there a way to use this method with Xamarin ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would need to use API Level 19, otherwise it is not available. If you don't want to use API 19 then consider using LoadUrl("javascript:").

Comment: Thanks. I see that the EvaluateScript method doesn't return anything... Is there a way to call a JavaScript method and get the returned value ?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a way to get the return value. If the function is your own you could send in a "callback". I have written some samples on how to create a cross-platform WebView hybrid, in Android's case you would use WebViewClient and parse out the URI in ShouldOverrideUrlLoading. Here is a link to the Android portion of the partial class WebHybrid: https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/blob/master/Core/SimplyMobile.Web/WebHybrid.Android.cs and the common(-ish) code portion: https://github.com/sami1971/SimplyMobile/blob/master/Core/SimplyMobile.Web/WebHybrid.cs

Comment: create an interface using addjavascriptinterface. Create a method in it, then you can call this method from the javascript and send it the value you want to return. Then you can use this value in your android java code.